# Spotlight for SQL Server LockType explanation required

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking

I have just started using `Spotlight` as I'm a software developer, but I am forced to identify database issues causing blocking (Spotlight shows me `AWAITING_COMMAND` at the points and all other processes are blocked, I assume this happens because the awaiting command involves a lock on a table that the rest of processes are trying to update). But this is not the case actually.

`In SQL Activity => Locks` I've noticed that there's plenty of locks in `S mode` on DATABASE (Lock Type), would anyone explain me what that actually means, is it harmful for the database and what may be the cause of it?

I've used `sys.dm_tran_locks` and what I'm receiving are locks on `resource_type DATABASE`. This is basically what I'd like to get insight on. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: We list all known (to us) wait types in the [Waitopedia](https://www.spotlightessentials.com/waitopedia/waits), although I can't find AWAITING_COMMAND in there nor on MSDN.
Which version are you using? You would gain most from also checking against the workload analysis

Answer (score 2):

Shared database locks are normal, simply meaning a connection is open in that database context.  That lock prevents another session from performing an operation like dropping the database while it's being used.

A session `AWAITING_COMMAND` that is blocking other sessions is an indicator the session still has an open transaction holding a lock on a resource (probably not database) that is incompatible with the other session's requested lock type.  That resource is typically a table or row but you mentioned that's not the case here. You can query `sys.dm_tran_locks` to identify granted and waiting locks on resources for each session.  I expect Spotlight would use this or similar a `DMV`.

Answer (score 1):

some reasons can be app waiting for user inputs,time outs with out proper exceptional handling.

you can easily simulate this by

Begin tran
Update authors ….
Waitfor delay ’10:00:00’   --- time out will occur here  (simulates long workload)
rollback

For second question on Slocks,These mean shared locks which are taken by database engine for any select statements.

Good place to know more on locking would be
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx

**References:**
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-what-is-a-sleeping-awaiting-command-session)

[Sleeping SPID blocking other transactions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/sleeping-spid-blocking-other-transactions)