# Sleeping sessions with an open transaction but empty input buffer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction

I have found out recently, that there are hanging several connections on our dev server (SQL Server 2016) with an open transaction. These transactions have been open for several days. I am using the query as follows:

```
SELECT session_id, se.database_id, status, open_transaction_count 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE open_transaction_count > 0
AND status = 'sleeping'
AND is_user_process = 1
```

It returns me several sessions with *open_transaction_count=1*. When I check the returned *session_ids* in the  *sys.dm_tran_session_transactions* and *sys.dm_tran_active_transactions* the existence of these transactions is proved in these views. All of the transactions have *transaction_state = 2*.

I would like to see the last SQL statement or batch within these sessions to identify what code in our application causes it and that is the issues. When I use:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER([mySPID])
```

I will receive a query for some of the *session_id*s, but no result for the others. The same result is when I try the query as follows:

```
SELECT se.session_id, se.database_id, se.status, se.open_transaction_count, qry.text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS se
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS con ON con.session_id = se.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(con.most_recent_sql_handle) AS qry
WHERE open_transaction_count > 0
AND status = 'sleeping'
AND is_user_process = 1
```

The interesting is that when I switch to the „problematic databases“ (those with no query text returned) and execute *DBCC OPENTRAN* the result is „No active open transaction“. I assume that it could be a select statement within an explicit unclosed transaction and so such a transaction is not returned with *DBCC OPENTRAN*. However, I am not sure with this interpretation.

I would like to know, why I cannot get the last statement/batch for these sessions and whether there is another way (then above mentioned) of how I can get it?

Comment: I'd suggest using [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) instead. Have a look at this [documentation page](http://whoisactive.com/docs/10_commands/) for possible ways of retrieving the text.

Comment: + what sp_BlitzErik mentioned look at this post. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/sleeping-spid-blocking-other-transactions?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This can sometimes happen when applications are using [implicit transactions](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/set-implicit_transactions-one-hell-bad-idea/)

It doesn't help that [sp_who2](https://littlekendra.com/2017/02/16/confused-by-sp_who2-dear-sql-dba-episode-30/) is really confusing -- you're better off with [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) or [sp_BlitzWho](http://firstresponderkit.org) to find running queries.

One dead giveaway of implicit transactions is seeing the query text like `begin tran` or `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0`.