# Stopping SQL Server Agent: Effect on runnings jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

On a server with MS SQL Server 2008 installed, we use the SQL Server Agent to schedule a large amount of SSIS-packages, all with unique schedules throughout the day.

Now and then, the server needs to be restarted (patching etc). Is it safe to right-click on SQL server agent and select 'stop'? The SSIS-packages are not that well-built and if they are stopped right in the middle of something data might become corrupted.

**So, does stopping SQL Server Agent mean that jobs are 'killed', or is it just so that no more jobs will be scheduled to run from that moment?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, jobs are aborted. Non-SQL process (eg CmdExec) are aborted too.
2. No more jobs run until SQL Server Agent is started again. Missing scheduled jobs will not be run.

After comment:

SQL Server Agent is just another connection to the DB engine. It will send an abort to the DB engine and all SQL jobs are stopped.

Abort means something here: it is a specific client action. See [SQL Server Transaction Timeout](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10912/630)